# SQL Server 2008 : select everything after '[' (multiple '[' present)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select everything in a string column after the `[`. Issue is there are multiple `[` in the string, which doesn't matter - I want to select everything after the 1st one.

I've tried several variances to try and get it to work but I can't.

```
RIGHT([Column 0], CHARINDEX('[', REVERSE([Column 0])) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use substring function also like below.

```
declare @str varchar(max)='some data[this is also some data[testing[hello[hi'

select substring(@str,charindex('[',@str,0)+1,len(@str))
```

## OUTPUT

```
this is also some data[testing[hello[hi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @S VARCHAR(100) = 'abc[123[1]222]'

Select SUBSTRING(  @S 
                 , CHARINDEX('[', @S) +1 
                 , LEN(@S)
                 )
```

Result:

```
123[1]222]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe next will do:

```
select substring([Column 0], charindex('[', [Column 0]) + 1, len([Column 0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.hope this will work for you.

[image]